# crontab has python Import Error on MacOS when running

Tags: python, macos, cron

My full code is

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui

APCS = "my APCS zoom link here"
webbrowser.open_new_tab(APCS)

print("running!!!!")
```

The crontab entry is `* * * * * cd Desktop/pp && /usr/bin/python a.py >> a.out 2>&1`

Crontab runs it when there's no `import pyautogui`. Otherwise, in `a.out` it shows me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

But it works when I run it from command line, I definitely have pyautogui.

Comment: The user used by cron might not have that module installed (or has no privilege to use it), if the module wasn't installed globally, just for your user. Also there is a possibility that you use the wrong python version, python, python3, and python3.6 are differ from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the python interpreter for the correct version, `python3` for python 3.x

Comment: What does that mean? I can't see a /usr/bin/python3 or anything like that.